# Add a line vertically in the middle

Tags: html, css

I want add a line vertically in the middle of a heading, and in the right side, I want to add another div. I can set the line in the middle of the heading, but when I add style for the right span, the line is no more in the middle.

Edit: The problem is with Firefox. It works fine on Chrome.

Please see the attached image:

[image]

Here's what I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"> 
    <h2><span class="text">Hello world</span><span class="right"></span></h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2 {   
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
    line-height: 0.1em; 
    margin: 10px 0 20px; 
} 

h2 span { 
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}

span.right{
    background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/

Comment: i found no issues in chrome

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was with floating, check out this updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/7/).

```
.box{
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

h2 .text {
    background-color:white;
    height: 10px; 
}

h2 {   
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
    line-height: 0; 
    margin: 10px 0 20px; 
} 

h2 span { 
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px; 
    float:left; 
}

span.right{
    background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/7/)

Comment: It doesn't help. Check your demo in Chrome.

Comment: @user2738640: Updated & tested in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/4/) , i have edited your html , and css

```
.line {
    float:left;
    min-width:400px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/8/

```
.box{
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


.text { 
    background:#fff; 
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px; 
}

.line {
    float:left;
    min-width:400px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    height: 10px;

}
.right{
    background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span.right{
    background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.text{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RecUE/5/)